# How to install Craft Commerce Shopping Feed Pro plugin

Tags: craft3, composer, plugin-craftcommerce3

I'm attempting to install the Craft Commerce Shopping Feed Pro plugin using the following:

`composer require kerosin/craft-google-shopping-feed-pro`

But I'm getting the following error:

`Could not find a matching version of package kerosin/google-shopping-feed-pro. Check the package spelling, your version constraint and that the package is available in a stability which matches your minimum-stability (stable).`

My Craft CMS is version 3.7.16 and the plugin requires a minimium of version 3.1

I'm not sure what to try next?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this plugin's package doesn't exist on Packagist.

https://packagist.org/search/?q=kerosin&reason=vendor_not_found